# Django URL dispatcher not working

Tags: python, django, django-urls

**urls.py** in `project` folder:

```
url('aaa', include('main_app.urls')),
```

**urls.py** in `main_app` folder:

```
url('aaa', views.index),
```

If I type `/aaa` in the address bar and press enter, it doesn't work. How do I make it work?

From my understanding, in the **urls.py** of the `project` folder, Django checks for a matching string in the **urls.py** of the `main_app` folder.

In both the `project` and `main_app` folders, it is `'aaa'` yet it doesn't work?

Comment: Try `url('aaa', views.index.as_view())`

Comment: `include` *includes under the prefix*... so your `views.index` there will be accessible as `aaa/aaa`...

Comment: @JonClements Hi, sorry I don't know what you mean. Can you give an example?